# G Suite domain alias - how to send email from Outlook or Windows Mail

Tags: email, google-workspace

I use the legacy free edition of G Suite, which allows you to create additional domain aliases (but not secondary domains).

For example, my primary domain in G Suite is @domainA.com, and I've sent up a domain alias @domainB.com

When I send an email address to me@domainB.com, I receive these emails into the inbox of that account (i.e. me@domainA.com)

But how do I send emails from me@domainB.com, e.g. from Windows 10 Mail?

(It's possible to do this from the Gmail web interface by visiting Settings > Accounts > Send Mail As)

I have tried the following to no avail:

- set up an alternative "from" address in Windows 10 Mail (there is no option)
- set up the account using the me@domainB.com ("the account can not be found", it's not technically the account username)
- set it up using plain old IMAP in Windows 10 Mail

Answer (score 0):

you mentioned Outlook, so have you tried using GSSMO? (G Suite Sync for Microsoft Outlook)

I am unsure of the effect on alias', but there is an option to add an account for delegation. Once your email is setup to sync you can use the following [option.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaMc8.png)

This may or may not work, as this method specifies account. Maybe it might be able to intelligently see it is an alias, as Gmail does when you change "Send Mail As.."